# how to make Upgradeable smart contract

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum

Which is the best approach for upgradeable smart contracts proxy approach or eternal storage approach?

Comment: Too general. Please describe each approach, provide a short coding example, share your thought about the pros and cons of each method, and then ask a more focused question with specific technical details.

Comment: Closing this as a duplicate for now; it may be reopened with the suggestions from @goodvibration.